# Best practice for decrypting text file using SALT, SEED, SecretKey in android

Tags: security, encryption, assets

I am new to security issues. I am trying to implement some basic (limited) protection of intellectual property in an android app by encrypting text assets. To do this, I have implemented the SimpleCrypto class described by S.Saurel here http://www.ssaurel.com/blog/how-to-use-cryptography-in-android-applications-2/. I plan to encrypt the data using a separate program and include the encrypted data as assets files, then decrypt them for use in the app. My question is what is the best practice for dealing with the SALT string and SEED string that are needed to decrypt the files? Should they be generated at run time or stored somehow? Should they be included in the crypto class, or generated elsewhere in the app and passed to the crypto class?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In this implementation "seed" is what you would think of as "password", and since you're not going to ask the user to provide a password, you can hardcode it, or store it in a file, or request it from a server at runtime, or whatever else. Be aware that a smart attacker will most likely be able to get at this password and use it to generate their own decryption key for your ciphertexts.

Salt is a non-secret value that acts as an [initialization vector](http://whatis.techtarget.com/definition/initialization-vector-IV) for encryption. Best-practice would dictate that you generate a random salt per cleartext, then provide the ciphertext and unencrypted seed to the client. The IV is typically dependent on the block size of your cipher used, and in your example there you're generating a 256-bit key, so you should generate a random 256-bit (64-byte) salt per cleartext and ship it with the ciphertext. You could do something as simple as producing a final string which is:

```
[2 bytes indicating length of salt][salt][ciphertext]
```

Then from that you can get your seed and ciphertext for decryption.